# RoR has_two relation: a Donation between two Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I have a problem I find difficult to search the web for an answer...

I have in my Ruby On Rails two models: User and Donation.

I want that a Relation has two user: user1 gives 10$ to user2.

This is what I came with:

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :value, :from_user_id, :to_user_id

  def from_user
     User.find(from_user_id)
  end

  def to_user
     User.find(to_user_id)
  end

end
```

But I would like to use relationships... Do you know the best way of doing this?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_one :from_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'from_user_id'
has_one :to_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'to_user_id'
```

Relations are nothing special... well, okay, they are now, but this essentially constructs the appropriate sql. I think. Haven't tried it.

Comment: OK thanks, that looks quite simple... I didn't know you could have "has_one" without "belongs_to"!

Comment: You actually want both of these to be belongs_to. belongs_to goes on the table which has the foreign key, which in this case should be Donation since a user may have many donations.

Comment: Yep, I realised that will trying to access my users. Thanks :)